# flex-basis auto and px mixed not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have 2 divs, one with a set width and one with an auto width using flex box. My understanding is that the div with flex-basis auto would take the remaining space in the row.

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; height:160px;  border:1px solid #00CC33">
  <div style="display:inline-block; flex-basis:auto; height:100%; border:1px solid #66BB33"></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; flex-basis:160px; height:100%; border:1px solid #66BB33;"></div>
</div>
```

The best is to invite you to check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w75tk4me/1/).

How to have the one div at 160px of width and the other one take the remaining space using flex?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex-basis` is the Flexbox property for `width` (when used in its default row direction), its default is `auto` and simply mean to be sized by content, kind of like an inline element work.

You should use `flex-grow: 1`, not `flex-basis: auto`.

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; height:160px;  border:1px solid #00CC33">
     <div style="display:inline-block; flex-grow: 1; height:100%; border:1px solid #66BB33"></div>
     <div style="display:inline-block; flex-basis:160px; height:100%; border:1px solid #66BB33;"></div>
</div>
```